# Typing the return of Higher Order Functions

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

For a function returning a function that wraps functions, I'm unable to preserve types from the wraped function.

```
type TResolverSignature<T> = [TParent, T, IContext, GraphQLResolveInfo]

function makeResolver(area: string){
    function  fn(
        target: (...theArgs: TResolverSignature<any>) => unknown,
        subarea: string
    ){
        return async (...theArgs: TResolverSignature<any>):  Promise<unknown> => {
            console.log(area, subarea);
            return await target(...theArgs)
        }
    }
    return fn
}
```

Now If I have some function and wrap it:

```
async function toBeWraped(...theArgs: TResolverSignature<{id: number}>): Promise<string> {
    return `sample ${theArgs[1].id}`
}

const wraped = makeResolver('bookkeeping')(toBeWraped, 'invoicing')
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-rpmnJHGtlHAEGbcOtrCq1kW0AABY2wdDvYjgNaF3bAModzGc5wbWx-LBWl4IIeorTG2oSxrNQQiDpdUAkv1fMDKLDkCJaW1Y4zT8xNFoGqRQmJYVAAHnMAD4V6AANr48ngAA0Fg-bVd1HdH-F9RSvOrRLvQAC6u66MwFw0NA6AeJmmBptYdCMLk1ZsNQTA8nUJRIgh1hIUqsBaPIiFOEqoDkAgjzHguNAABTnAgUaIlkACUJh-DcZGERR1g8dYDHcTcomxEguTgC8DEBKIUAoJYEmwC8R7AaekLQtg17jgQt7sSu96Ztm9C5m+Imia8WBmsxrExqJnHmaJqBaQJcQEIRoAyQE8mKVkykWHRrRIGemmXigV46XpLygCcvQCleRk5tY95EveXEWRlomVAJxBsEhzp8nwmYQDASLwHIjygFyKDoPcJw0OQcCwMhTGoAgH6wFZzH6eOqhelkHxqBojmZegxGCJoXqtSg7WWdZbXsQA3CNGXOZerk8ggzgQMgkleXJ6i+bA7EraiFlnU5VDrR4eaTloY0ocY-D0UgD7UbRamMb4Zr0PQ9yPCgeFZL4J0YvuVXEU9n20A+6VidIKAvM9QUMU4lAAGKIR+vilEI9BwR8IMoruTLmDA8BwKASpoPQ8hqFuyioKovH8ahoCSaAOHsCo2huR5vFEQJaMoJjhH7T5SkqYF6nnlp4UmNAkagNYW4WkgrhRTFcV6leIJImlIlrUgAnCrAFCyGgAAkJgS35j4AIxgaIiuuDak7ZSVlMYublZ8NDsByQjeh0AQuKqMKqOHUptwAAy+u4tuwLc9tjrYH6J7cABMvpgenUd+bcADM8f6alWvePFiUmclNq6Ga8akpz47GNtDDmmgxqqPJrwUGgcQQKHIuIU8TIRxncemAn+dJynpiKy8KvkGrrh5wp0fZ6YuclWvBfF5Ppf3rFFc63rWS3sKQA)

I want `wraped` to have the same parameter and return type as `toBeWraped`. I experimented with generic types in `makeResolver.fn()` to replace `any` and `unknown` there but to no success.

Comment: What is `TResolverSignature`? Also note that should be _wrapped_.

Comment: I think all you need is basic use of [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html): https://tsplay.dev/NnX0BW. It's not clear what you experimented with, or what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Basically, I want to get rid of the any and unknown. function fn<TResolverSignature<P>, T>(target: (...theArgs: TResolverSignature<P>) => Promise<T>, ... feels to express the right thing, but does not compile.

Comment: Where is P coming from there?

Comment: From the actual implementation of `target` https://gist.github.com/mdornseif/5eb7ec8dc0f2ab92d1234c1e6420a6bd is a real world example. E.g.  async function target(...theArgs: TResolverSignature<{ d: string }>): Promise<Tsomething[]> {

Comment: Please don't post off-site links, especially not in comments, include the [mre] in the question.

Comment: Sorry. I seem not to be able to find the right balance for a MWE here that fit's your need. I tried, but may be hampered by my lack of understanding of the problem domain. My goal is to get rid of all the unknowns and anys in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

The link by [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) got me started. Frankly, I was not aware that you can have multiple type parameters like `<P, T>`.

This gives me tight type bindings as desired:

```
function makeResolver(area: string){
    function  fn<P, T>(
        target: (...theArgs: TResolverSignature<P>) => Promise<T>,
        subarea: string
    ){
        return async (...theArgs: TResolverSignature<P>):  Promise<unknown> => {
            console.log(area, subarea);
            return await target(...theArgs) as T

        }
    }
    return fn
}
```